# Why can I not import data from CSV file to the table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an interesting challenge. I am learning how to use COPY function in SQL. I need to import a data from .CSV to the table (PostgreSQL server). But every time when I try to do this I get this message:

```
ERROR:  could not open file "/Users/olenaskoryk/Desktop/us_counties_2010.csv" for reading: Permission denied
HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
SQL state: 42501
```

My query is:

```
COPY us_counties_2010
FROM '/Users/olenaskoryk/Desktop/us_counties_2010.csv'
WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER);
```

As you see I am working on Mac.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Are client and server in the same machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that PostgreSQL is not running locally on your computer. That's why the server can't read your local file.

You may want to do this through a [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) session using the `\copy` command.

```
$ psql your_db_connection_url
psql (10.5)
Type "help" for help.

db=# \copy us_counties_2010 FROM '/Users/olenaskoryk/Desktop/us_counties_2010.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER);
```

Psql's [`\copy`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-META-COMMANDS-COPY) command uses `COPY FROM STDIN` under the hood, passing the contents of the local file through standard input to the server, circumventing the limitation of the server not being able to read the local file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Unfortunately, I am not familiar how to work with commands. I assume that we are talking about Terminal. I know very simple things..how to work with folder and how to create files using commands.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I don't know from what I should start. Because I can not figur our without help how to work wit that things that you advised to do 
Psql's \copy command uses COPY FROM STDIN under the hood, passing the contents of the local file through standard input to the server, circumventing the limitation of the server not being able to read the local file."

Comment: @ElenaSkoryk, I'm not sure if you figured it out since you've accepted my answer. If not, how are you connecting to your database currently?

Comment: HI, I accepted this because you gave me some insights. But when I used Terminal it did't run this command db=# \copy us_counties_2010 FROM '/Users/olenaskoryk/Desktop/us_counties_2010.csv' WITH (FORMAT CSV, HEADER);

Comment: It gave me notification that permission is denied

Comment: I am using postgresql , I connected to the server

Comment: I saved file.csv with data that is meant to use further for study different functions of SQL. It is a big frustration for me. I don't know what I did wrong. I installed new version Postgresql than download data to the .csv file. I created a table and then stuck there because COPY function doesn't  work  for me.

Answer (score 0):

The HINT is relevant.  The SQL server is not running as you, and does not have the right to read your file.

Give it permissions (which may require giving permissions to containing directories), or put in in a universally readable place.  (like perhaps a TEMP directory.)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am not familiar how to work with Terminal. I need to import my .csv file to TABLE that I created on Postgresql. Every time when I try to do it it gives me a message : Permission denied. I created couple times new password using Terminal but it doesn't work for me. Any advice? I am not a programmer I just want to know how to work wit data base using SQL. Please, help me. Maybe you know some courses how to work with programs using command line? Thank you in advance.